# How to get a universal binary with both architectures from Homebrew on Mavericks

Tags: macos, homebrew

I need to install Cairo for the use of a 32-bit application on Mavericks.

After first uninstalling libpng, I have succeeded in forcing a complete recompile of Cairo and all its dependents (libpng, fontconfig, pixman, glib) using

```
brew install --build-from-source cairo
```

Showing the `brew info` on these libraries indicates they were built from source, and built as a universal binary.  However `lipo -info` reports the architecture only as x86_64.

How can I get Homebrew to install Cairo and all its dependents with both i386 and x86_64 architectures?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `homebrew` no longer supports the --universal flag and the project does not intend to from their comments.